# UIScrollView as UIControl

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, swift4, uicontrol

I am implementing a UIControl using UIScrollView. I wish to send .valueChanged event when user scrolls the scroll view with finger, not otherwise. To do this, I need to compare the currentValue I compute when the scrolling happens, and if it is different than previous value, I send a .valueChanged event via sendActionsForControlEvents API. My questions:

(a) What is the most reliable way in all cases to know that user dragged the scroll view(scrolling can also happen in my code using automated API) -- scrollView.isDragging or scrollView.isTracking, or both?

(b) What is the way to notice change in currentValue (without storing previous value)? I am doing this using Swift 4 but it doesn't seems to give old value:

```
 private(set) public var currentValue = Int(0) {
    willSet (newValue) {
        NSLog("Old value \(currentValue), new \(newValue)")
    }
 }
```

Comment: 1. Why not simply use didScroll delegate method? It should be triggered when there is a change in visible frame. Using it with isDragging should almost solve your problem. 2. If you want to only track user scrolling then what about decelerating? At that point I believe isDragging is already false. There is one of the delegate methods that gives you information of ending a drag which includes a boolean value that the scroll view will decelerate. IF you need to handle this as well I assume using delegates alone should work best.

Comment: My problem is, sometimes I also do use automated API to set contentOffset -- scroller.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: scroller.contentOffset.x, y: offset), animated: true). This also invokes scrollViewDidScroll:, correct? The decelerate API is triggered when scroller is about to decelerate and stop. I use both the APIs, but need to distinguish automated ones from user generated.

Comment: Exactly. That is why you need a flag like `isUserScrolling` which is best set to true when dragging begins; set to false when dragging ends if deceleration is false; set to false when deceleration ends. Then on `didScroll` simply use this `isUserScrolling`. User is dragging when `isUserScrolling` is true.

Comment: As in answer you need a delegate alone. This might be even worse then subclassing though. I am unsure there is a stable solution without it but you might be able to swizzle a few methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments using delegates I believe the solid solution should look something similar to:

```
class MyClass: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    private var isUserDragging: Bool = false

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if isUserDragging {
            // Should trigger only when scroll view visible frame changes and user is dragging
            print("User is dragging")
        }
    }

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        isUserDragging = true // Should only be called when user starts dragging
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        if decelerate == false {
            isUserDragging = false // Disable user dragging only if no deceleration will be performed
        }
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        isUserDragging = false // When deceleration is done user is not dragging anymore
    }

}
```

Now you should be able to get your event within `scrollViewDidScroll`.